# Can't load image into Mat OpenCV + Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to read a png image into OpenCV `Mat`,
It's reading my image but I got `0` for row and column
here's my code.

```
obCast = Highgui.imread(getClass().getResource("/_0cast.png").getPath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Comment: try without the `getClass().getResource("/_0cast.png").getPath()` thing, i.e with an absolute path like: "/home/my/_0cast.png". also, imread() can't read from a jar.

Comment: It still does load the image but still has a size of 0 rows and cols

Comment: this is what I'm doing.
`obCast = Highgui.imread(getClass().getResource("/_0cast.png").getPath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

System.out.println(obCast.rows());`

And I still got 0 in rows